# How to make a user click on a "class" when the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a user click on a "class", when the page loads. I tried this code in google chrome console, and it works.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('CLASSHere');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
   inputs[i].click();
}
```

But when i paste the same code in my website at the end of the page before `</body>` tag. It does not work. I do not have much knowledge about javascript,  jQuery.

Comment: You pasted this? `<script>var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('CLASSHere');
for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++)
{ inputs[i].click(); }</script>` ?

Comment: Remove `javascript:` and surround the code with `<script>` code `</script>`.  There's more to it, but that should get you going.   The code you have is meant to be added in a single line to an anchor, eg `<a href='javascript:var...`

Comment: @freedomn-m - it is a bookmarklet and was likely created to run from the location bar

Comment: tried this now  '<script type="text/javascript">
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('_49vh _2pi7');
for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++)
{ inputs[i].click(); }</script>'

Comment: But still do not work

Comment: I did not add any <script src=""></script> code in the page, do i need to?

Comment: No, you don't need `src=''` bit.   Make sure your new `<script>` is right at the bottom of the code, just before `</body>` and that you do have elements with that classname.

Answer (score 0):

**Try using `window.onload`**

```
window.onload = function(){
   var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('CLASSHere');
   for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
     inputs[i].click();
   }
}
```

> More details about [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Hope this will work perfectly for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        window.onload = function(){
            var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("itemclass");
            for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
                elements[i].click();
            }
        }
        
        function clickevent1(){
            console.log("1 Clicked");
        }
        
        function clickevent2(){
            console.log("2 Clicked");
        }
        
        function clickevent3(){
            console.log("3 Clicked");
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button class="itemclass" onclick="clickevent1()">1</button>
    <button class="itemclass" onclick="clickevent2()">2</button>
    <button class="itemclass" onclick="clickevent3()">3</button>
</body>

</html>
```